# Why ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() return the array which contains only 0's?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage

I have the next code:

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/img.jpg"));
    image = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

// get array of image
final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pixels));
```

And I get next output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. And yes, everything is OK with my file. Because, when I run `sout(image)` get something like that `BufferedImage@6f7fd0e6: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 1280 height = 720 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0`

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your code is

```
image = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

You are never drawing anything into `image`. (The image you read from the filesystem is stored in `img` not `image`.)

Comment: thanks, but when I call `((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()` I will get ClassCastException `DataBufferByte cannot be cast to class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt`, so what can I do?

Comment: Depends on *why* you want to access the image's `DataBuffer` and why you want to cast to `DataBufferInt`. What do you want do with your image?

Comment: it's all right, i already found solution, thank you

   'Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
   g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);'